# Joining from another table multiple times in a MySQL query

Tags: mysql, join

I am trying to do multiple joins on the same MySQL table, but am not getting the results that I expect to get.  Hopefully someone can point out my mistake(s).

```
Table 1 -  cpe Table

|id | name
|----------
| 1 | cat
| 2 | dog
| 3 | mouse
| 4 | snake
-----------

Table 2 - AutoSelect

|id  | name   |  cpe1_id |  cpe2_id  | cpe3_id |
|-----------------------------------------------
| 1  | user1  |  1       |  3        | 4       |
| 2  | user2  |  3       |  1        | 2       |
| 3  | user3  |  3       |  3        | 2       |
| 4  | user4  |  4       |  2        | 1       |
------------------------------------------------
```

I would like to see an output of

```
user1 | cat   | mouse  |  snake  |
user2 | mouse | snake  |  dog    | 
..etc
```

Here is what I have tried

```
SELECT * FROM AutoSelect
LEFT JOIN cpe ON 
( cpe.id = AutoSelect.cpe1_id ) AND
( cpe.id = AutoSelect.cpe2_id ) AND
( cpe.id = AutoSelect.cpe3_id )
```

I get blank results.  I thought i knew how to do these joins, but apparently when I'm trying to match cpe?_id with the name of the cpe table.

Thanks in advance for any assistance.

Comment: Are you sure output should be user2 - "mouse snake dog" and not "mouse cat dog"?

Answer (score 1):

You need left join 3 times as well.  Currently your query only joins 1 time with 3 critieria as to the join.  This should do:

```
SELECT a.name, cpe1.name, cpe2.name, cpe3.name FROM AutoSelect as a
LEFT JOIN cpe as cpe1 ON ( cpe1.id = a.cpe1_id ) 
LEFT JOIN cpe as cpe2 ON ( cpe2.id = a.cpe2_id ) 
LEFT JOIN cpe as cpe3 ON ( cpe3.id = a.cpe3_id )
```

And you probably mean to INNER JOIN rather than LEFT JOIN unless NULL values are allowed in your AutoSelect table.

Answer (score 0):

I think your design is wrong.

With tables like that, you get it the way it's meant to be in relational databases :

```
table 1 : animal
 id  name
 1   cat
 2   dog
 3   mouse
 4   snake


table 2 : user
|id  | name   |
|--------------
| 1  | user1  |
| 2  | user2  |
| 3  | user3  |
| 4  | user4  |

table 3 : association
|id_user | id_animal|
|--------------------
| 1      | 1        |
| 1      | 3        |
| 1      | 4        |
| 2      | 3        |
| 2      | 1        |
| 2      | 2        |
| 3      | 3        | 
| 3      | 2        
| 4      | 4        |
| 4      | 2        |
| 4      | 1        |
---------------------
```

Then :

select u.name, a.name from user u, animal a, association ass where ass.user_id = u.id and ass.animal_id = a.id;

Comment: Yes, jerome g, you are correct.  The design is incorrect.  I acquired responsibility for a database and MANY tables built for Yii.  What I posted is only 1/8 of what the columns within the table contain.  I tries to shorten with "animals".  :) <br /><br /> Unfortunately without me going in and changing a lot of the pages, I have to perform a query against this table to pull data out.  The joins are going to be a pain.  Thanks for the responses, I am going to test both ideas out!  --be back in afew

Answer (score 0):

In this case, your solution won't produce a good dynamic database. There are other ways to make combinations of multiple tables. I can show you by my own database what you should use and when you should use this solution. The scheme is in dutch, but you'll probably understand the keywords.

Like you, I had to combine my windmills with a kWh-meter, which has to measure the energyproduction of my windmills. What you should do, is this case, is making another table(in my case molenkWhlink). Make sure your tables are INNODB-types(for making Foreign keys). What I've done is combining my meters and mills by putting a pointer(a foreign key) of their ID(in Dutch Volgnummer) in the new table. An advantage you may not need, but I certainly did, is the fact I was able to extend the extra table with connection and disconnection info like Timestamps and metervalues when linking or unlinking. This makes your database way more dynamic.

In my case, I Also had a table for meassurements(metingoverzicht). As you can see in the scheme, I've got 2 lines going from Metingoverzicht to molenkwhlink. The reason for this is quite simple. All meassurements I take, will be saved in table Metingoverzicht. Daily meassurements(which are scheduled) will have a special boolean put on, but unscheduled meassurements, will also me saved here, with the bollean turned off. When switching meters, I need the endvalue from the leaving meter and the startvalue from the new meter, to calculate the value of todays eneryproduction. This is where your solution comes in and an extra table won't work. Usually, when you need just one value from another table a JOIN will be used. The problem in this case is, I've got 2 meassurementIDs in 1 link(1 for connecting and 1 for disconnecting). They both point to the same tablecolumn, because they both need to hold the same type of information. That is when you can use a double JOIN from one table towards the other. Because, both values will only be used once, and just needed to be saved in a different place to avoid having 1 action stored on different locations, which should always be avoided.

http://s1101.photobucket.com/user/Manuel_Barcelona/media/schemedatabase.jpg.html